# How to fix this problem bellow? An Javascript/Ajax problem

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

hello I'm doing an asp net core application that use ajax and an login.js to carry data to my API, but when i try to execute JSON.stringify(formData) in the browser i got the error message Uncaught ReferenceError: formData is not defined
at :1:16
I tried a lot of things to fix the problem someone can help?

```
function logar(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = {
        email: $("input[name='email']").val(),
        password: $("input[name='password']").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        url: "https://localhost:7291/api/User",
        success: function (result) {
            // Lógica de sucesso
        },
        error: function (error) {
            // Lógica de erro
        }
    });
};
```

this is my page

```
@model SquadManager.Models.UserViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<link href="~/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section>
    <h1>Autenticação</h1>
<form>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="@Model.Email" placeholder="Username/e-mail" />
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="@Model.Password" placeholder="Senha" />
        <a href="#">Esqueceu a senha?</a>

        <button type="submit" onclick="logar(event);">Login</button>
</form>

    <label>Não tem um conta?  <a href="#">Crie sua conta aqui!</a> </label>
</section>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/login.js"></script>
```

page result error [console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Vv9.png)

Comment: The variable `formData` only exists within the `logar` function.  If you try to type JSON.stringify(formData) in the console (and not use it within the logar func) it will give the error you are getting.

Comment: well thanks to explain that :) my API is work ok and the formData is returning the objects in the right way i changed th function to work not in the onclick but in the on submit

Answer (score 0):

As James explained i can't call JSON.stringify(formData) out of the function logar so i changed the function logar to this code bellow that works in the event onsubmit of the form

```js
$('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = {
        email: $("input[name='email']").val(),
        password: $("input[name='password']").val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        url: "https://localhost:7291/api/User",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.response == "ok")
                alert("Logado")
            else
                alert("Credenciais Inválidas")
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
});
```

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vBqQ.png)